# Mongoose virtual set function not called when value is object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a virtual of mixed type. For example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose') // version 3.3.1

var FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema( { x: Number } );

FooSchema.virtual('v').set( function(value){ 
  console.log("SETTING", value); 
});

var Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema);

new Foo( { v:1 } );
new Foo( { v:[] } );
new Foo( { v:{} } );
```

When I run this code I get:

```
SETTING 1
SETTING []
```

As you'll notice it never shows "SETTING {}", any reason why this doesn't work?

[Reference to issue on Github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1154)

Comment: What about when the object has properties?

Comment: The result is the same when the object has properties.

Comment: weird, +1 I am interested in this as well. I may investigate tomorrow if no one has answered by then.

Answer (score 1):

This was an open issue in Mongoose that's been [fixed in a recent commit](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commit/26f2534166f6a80b1f185cdaaadc9ed7fc0b01d0) by [Aaron Heckmann](https://github.com/aheckmann).